# Purpose of "а" in sentences

Tags: грамматика, предлоги

> Почему нет, а пошли.

What is the point of "a" in that sentence, and in general?

Comment: [A](https://ru.wiktionary.org/wiki/%D0%B0#%D0%97%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5_2), #4

Comment: this "a" here is as meant in "but", "no" (see Russian "но" too :>). See the latin prefix "a-" as negation too :> This sentence denies your refusal,  and encourages you to go together him.

Answer (score 3):

"a" is likely used here to emphasize negligent tint of phrase. However, it is not necessary here.

Answer (score 0):

*"А"* has (too) many different meanings. Here it could be one of:

1. Conjunction to emphasize fast topic transition.
2. Interjection to show determination; note that in this case a comma is required: *Почему нет? А, пошли.*

Also, in live speech the interjection *"а"* is generally much longer than the conjunction.

Answer (score 0):

Probably so: And why not ? Let's go.

> А почему бы и нет ? Пойдем.

Answer (score 0):

As a native speaker I'd personally rather say:

> А почему (бы и) нет, пошли!

In your example "а" gives kind of a spontaneous character to the sentence, it's like I was probably unsure about going, and now I've finally decided to go:

Compare:

> А: Посмотри на этих девушек у бара, пойдем познакомимся.

> Б: Почему нет, пошли.

and:

> А: Посмотри на этих девушек у бара, пойдем познакомимся.

> Б: Да они с нами и разговаривать-то не будут.

> А: Да ладно тебе, не бойся. Все у нас получится.

> Б: Почему нет, а пошли!

Also it could be an answer to a question where "а" is used as "давай":

> А не пойти ли нам в кино? (= Давай пойдем в кино)

> Почему нет, а пошли.

Answer (score -1):

I believe the punctuation in the given sentence is wrong. It should be

> Почему нет? А пошли.

The sentence seems silly to me because it delivers the same message twice. It's like saying `of course, for sure, no doubt` in a row.

As for the meaning of the conjunction `а`, I'd say it's safe to translate it as an English word `though`.